# How to read a value from response header in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I am getting following header in response :
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Date: Mon, 11 Apr 2016 10:36:10 GMT 
content-disposition: attachment; filename=result.xml; 
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=access Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
 I want to read filename from header, how can I use regular expression to capture this value ?

Answer (score 25):

1. Add [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) **as a child** of the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) which returns above headers
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Apply to: `Main sample only` or `Main sample and sub-samples` depending on whether header comes in main response or nested responses
   - Field to check: `Response Headers`. This bit is **super** important
   - Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `filename`
   - Regular Expression: `filename=(.+?);`
   - Template: `$1$`

     [image: Regular Expression Configuration]
3. Refer extracted value as `${filename}` where required

---

4. References:

   - [Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
   - [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) With JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)

Comment: Actually I am saving response in a file and want to give name which I am reading from header. But after doing this I am getting file name as ${filename}1.xml....not result.xml, I am using Save Responses to a file listener to save the result.

Comment: Double check that you successfully extracted the variable with [Debug Sampler](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script)

Comment: For a complete header value I used something like Regular Expression = `content-disposition:\s*(.+)`. The `\s*` is optional but it trims leading whitespace off the value.

Answer (score 1):

Use a PostProcessor element and refer required element with `ctx.getPreviousResult().XXX`, for example:

`ctx.getPreviousReult().getResponseCode();`

`ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseHeaders();`

Here the output goes to file:

`log.info(ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseDataAsString());`

`log.info(ctx.getPreviousResult().getContentType());`

`log.info(ctx.getPreviousResult().getUrlAsString());`

Comment: Good answer. Friendly tip: you can markup text as `code` by surrounding it in back ticks ` 
Single for a line, three for a block.