# How to read a value of Location from response header in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I am getting below Header Response :-

```
HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
Content-Length: 0
Location: https://localhost:111/api_path/916e0a93-552f-46fd-84c4-6cecac92209a
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcR2l0SHViXFJNTVxFZGdlUHJvdG90eXBlXEVkZ2VQcm90b3R5cGVcYXBpXHYxXFNubXBcR2V0VjFBc3luYw==?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 30 May 2019 13:13:24 GMT
```

how can I use regular expression to capture the below value from Location ?

```
916e0a93-552f-46fd-84c4-6cecac92209a
```

I am not saving my response in file and i want a value of Location from Response Header

I tried below way but getting NOT FOUND as it is default, if i remove default then it will show null

[image]

Comment: I try to use like 


Regular Expression : https://localhost:111/api_path/{.*}


but console shows null when i try to print it. and Jmeter shows waring as 


RegexExtractor: No variable '' found to process by RegexExtractor 'Regular Expression Extractor', skipping processing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a value from response header in jmeter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36547421/how-to-read-a-value-from-response-header-in-jmeter)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7294900/user7294900 i tried this but it not solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

Replace your regular expression with

```
Location: https:.+api_path\/(.*?)\n
```

Make sure you use **Apply to** `Main sample only`.